# Configurate Tomcat 8 with GZIP

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, compression, gzip

I'm trying to set GZIP in Tomcat, I've shown a lot of examples but anyone works for me. Below you can see my server.xml configuration and an example of request:

server.xml

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443"
               useSendfile="false"
               compression="force" compressionMinSize="1024" noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
       compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/javascript,text/css,application/javascript"/>
```

request:

[image: request with GZIP enabled]

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer, I've disabled my antivirus and compression works fine.