# Tomcat compression with Host Alias is not working properly

Tags: tomcat, compression, gzip

I am trying to enable GZIP compression on a tomcat8 server and I am facing some problem when I want to use it with Alias. Considering the following configuration of server.xml for the connector :

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443"
           useSendfile="false"
           compression="on"
           compressionMinSize="128" 
           noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata" />
```

And here is the Host on which I want to enable the compression :

```
<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

    <Alias>alias-test.first</Alias>
    <Alias>myalias-test.second</Alias>
</Host>
```

This host as some Alias on which my application is working. A can access it on localhost and on the URL defined by the Alias

The compression is working when I request http://localhost:8080. But it doesn't work when I access one of the alias, http://alias-test.first:8080

Finaly, here is my host file on my computer :

```
127.0.0.1           alias-test.first
127.0.0.1           myalias-test.second
```

Are there a specific configuration in tomcat to use compression when I try to access my application from many URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you've got the same problem than this stack overflow question : [see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481597/configurate-tomcat-8-with-gzip?rq=1)

Try and disable your antivirus if you're using a windows server, it might be blocking the url for compression.